# Reading in a JSON from S3 bucket using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've tried to read about this but have not come up with anything yet. I have a JSON that gets output to an S3 bucket daily. I have a web app built in JavaScript that I'd like to be able to simply read in the JSON from the S3 bucket without downloading the JSON every day and re-committing in GitHub, etc etc.

How does one read in a JSON that's hosted on an S3 bucket?  Ideally, I'd like this to work like a live connection (rather than downloaded), since the JSON will be re-uploaded to S3 every day.

Is AWS SDK for JavaScript what I need?  To clarify, this is an app built in vanilla JavaScript, not Node, so a fairly simple solution would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of a 'live connection' to S3 isn't practical, but an appropriate alternative would be to trigger your JavaScript code to run whenever a JSON file is uploaded to your S3 bucket.

To do that, write and deploy a simple Node.js Lambda function and configure S3 to trigger the Lambda function when a JSON file is uploaded. Your Lambda function would use the [JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html) to get the JSON file and do whatever processing is required. Your Lambda function should be configured with an IAM role that permits it to get the uploaded object.

If you prefer to use a language other than JavaScript/TypeScript, see [AWS Tools](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) for the list of supported language SDKs and [Lambda runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) for the list of supported Lambda runtimes.

Comment: Thanks.. is there a non- node solution? I don’t quite have the bandwidth to learn node right now. Alternatively I could just do crontab on Mac terminal to download the s3 json to my local repo daily.. but that’s not really working for me right now ..

Comment: yeah i want to use javascript... just not node.  Why is live connection impractical?  i.e. something like a fetch to the url that reads the json using Javascript.. this sounds reasonable right?

Comment: Where would you propose to run this JavaScript? In a browser? On the live connection question, I'm not even sure what you mean by 'live connection'. Issuing a fetch to a public URL is perfectly feasible with S3 (using pre-signed URLs or public objects) but there's nothing about that I'd describe as a 'live connection'.

Comment: yeah, this is a web app built from javascript deployed over github.  Right now i have a crontab in mac that downloads the s3 file daily.  If there was a way to not have to do that, that would be ideal.  Ideally I could fetch the url in javascript.  does this make sense?

Comment: You can store the JSON in S3 and make it available via URL, then use whatever client-side fetch/request library you like. If the object can be made public then do so and simply fetch https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/xyz.json. If it cannot be made public then either find a way to give the client a pre-signed URL to the object or find  way to get AWS credentials to the client so you can use the JavaScript SDK (in the browser) to issue a GetObject request.

Comment: trying these examples (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) but giving me  error: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html